# Rendering an image with a value greater than 1

Tags: rendering

So in Blender I modeled a tiny black-and-white model (using emission shaders) that I'm using as a bump map. I've determined that I'd like to increase the strength of the bump map on my materials, but I've used this texture on so many materials that I'd hate to have to go through manually and tweak the slider.

Since black has an RGB value of (0,0,0), and white has a value of (1,1,1), I believe that changing the value of the white colors to, say, (1.5,1.5,1.5) would solve this issue. Problem is, I don't know how to render this image that way.

Could somebody please provide some clarification on this issue?